# Rolify: как удалить связь между пользователем и ролью, а не саму роль?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

На [этой странице](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Usage) продемонстрированы методы, позволяющие создавать роль или связь (или все вместе) или полностью уничтожать связь и роль вместе.

Вот именно это и напрягает:

> Уничтожение связи и самой роли

Банальный пример:

Есть роль "admin" и N пользователей. Доем нескольким пользователям роль "admin":

```
user = User.find(1) # IDs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
user.add_role :admin
```

Этот метод добавит связь в таблицу `users_roles`.

Через некоторое время понадобилось удалить у одного из пользователей роль "admin". По ссылке выше нам смело демонстрируют:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.remove_role :admin
```

Но вот только этот метод удалит саму роль и все связи с другими пользователями.

Как быть?

Comment: покажите лог момента удаления роли или добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: Бегло проехался по коду, нашёл всего одно обстоятельство, когда это может произойти: **если это был последний пользователь с этой ролью**. И это [отключаемо](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/blob/34ed256cd8bd904810fa05bb75e6f438a1a3cb8c/lib/rolify/configure.rb#L44). Подходит под условия вашего эксперимента? :)

Comment: @D-side перед тем как опубликовать вопрос, а прошелся по сценарию, когда роль уже занята другими пользователями. Ну, я это и написал в предпоследнем абзаце :) Я вообще воспроизвел все ситуации. Всегда удалялась и сама роль, и все связи со всеми пользователями. Это странно, да. Хотя бы потому, что автор gem'а по-любому об этом думал. Но я описываю ситуацию на коробочной связке Devise, Rolify и Pundit.

Comment: А залейте эту коробочную связку на гитхаб, например. Потому что из документации к Rolify то поведение, что вы описываете, вообще не следует.

Comment: @D-side весь проект я не могу залить :) Но единственное что я проделал в той связке - это выполнил этапы установки каждого gem'а. В настройках их не лазал.

Comment: Если будет время, я попробую это воспроизвести, но я б готовился к исходу "не воспроизведётся", и тогда будет не очень понятно, что делать.

Comment: @D-side заранее спасибо